# How can I get the depth of a node from data.tree object?

Tags: r, treeview, data-manipulation

Let's say I have a test data like this:

```
library(data.tree)

 df <- structure(list(parent = c("part1", "part3", "part7", "part4", 
"part9", "part1"), child = c("part7", "part12", "part4", "part27", 
"part10", "part13"), children = c("part4", "", "part27", "", 
"", ""), children1 = c("part27", "", "", "", "", ""), pathString = c("Root/part1/part7/part4/part27", 
"Root/part3/part12//", "Root/part7/part4/part27/", "Root/part4/part27//", 
"Root/part9/part10//", "Root/part1/part13//")), .Names = c("parent", 
"child", "children", "children1", "pathString"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
df$children <- ""
df$children1 <- ""
```

I created a data.tree as follows:

```
test_tree <- as.Node(df)
print(test_tree, limit = 50)
```

I'm trying to get the depth of each parent node in the tree from the root.
Tried reading the docs but I couldn't find anything related to depth of a tree.

Is there a way in R to get the depth of the tree from this data.tree plot ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'depth of each parent node in the tree from the root'. Maybe this?

```
library(data.tree)
data(acme)
print(acme, 'height', 'level')
```

This prints like this:

```
                          levelName height level
1  Acme Inc.                             3     1
2   ¦--Accounting                        2     2
3   ¦   ¦--New Software                  1     3
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards      1     3
5   ¦--Research                          2     2
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line              1     3
7   ¦   °--New Labs                      1     3
8   °--IT                                2     2
9       ¦--Outsource                     1     3
10      ¦--Go agile                      1     3
11      °--Switch to R                   1     3
```

Note that `height` and `level` are properties/actives on `Node`. So you could also call `acme$height`.
For a list of all actives, type `?Node`.